# AS3. How to change character's template in adobe flash cs5 using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, templates, adobe, character

I'm creating flash game. Here will be abillity to choose one of two (or more) character's. So I have in library created symbol `hero`. It have 7 animations on click (moving, jumping, attacking etc..) 
[image: as3]

So I want to create something like hero 2, that player could choose which one likes more. Just how to do that? Create new layer in `hero` and add animations or how?

I'm asking that because in Action Script 3 I'm adding hero in this case and It always will add the same:

```
        private function create_hero()
    {

        addChild(Hero);
        Hero.gotoAndStop("stay");
        Hero.x = stage.stageWidth/2;;
        Hero.y = ground.y - 60;
        Hero.x_speed = 0;
        Hero.y_speed = 0;
    }
```

Maybe here is abillity to make something like that `layer2.addChild(Hero);`?

Or I need to create new symbol `hero2`? I don't like this idea, because I have long code to control `hero`, so for every character I'll need to dublicate code. Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to dynamically create an instance `Hero` at game start based on the game player's selection. You indeed create two (or more) symbols in Flash CS, with common frame labeling (you can use different animation lengths for different heroes), then, once you've got your hero selection (`hero1`,`hero2`,`hero3` etc, regardless of their amount) you get the class name from selection and get your `Hero` variable to be assigned an instance of the respective class. An example:

```
static var heroes:Array=[hero1,hero2,hero3]; // note: symbol names!
var Hero:MovieClip; // note, not "hero1" or anything, but general MovieClip type
public function selectHero(what:int):void {
    // this is called with correct "what", design yourself. I use array index
    var whatHero:Class = heroes[what]; // get selected hero symbol
    if (Hero && Hero.parent) Hero.parent.removeChild(Hero);
    // clean up previous hero. Drop listeners here, if any
    Hero = new whatHero(); // get new hero
    // process as usual, don't forget to "addChild(Hero)" somewhere
}
```

How this works: First, you give the player a hero selection dialogue, and call `selectHero` with proper value of `what` (0 for `hero1`, 1 for `hero2`, etc, as you make your `heroes` array). Then, the `whatHero` variable is assigned the corresponding class (yes, one can assign classes to variables in AS3!) And then the class gets instantiated via `new` construction, and the resultant movie clip is then assigned to `Hero` variable. After this is done, you can use your hero as before.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how can I use It for now? I've created 2 buttons for example:    `btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectHero(hero1));
btn_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectHero(hero2));`
But this not working

Comment: Wrap `selectHero(hero2)` into a function with a parameter of `Event` type, and make it the listener for `btn_2`, same for another button. You give a **function** to `addEventListener`, not an expression.